# How to fetch top 10 rows from a table depending on a field value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an 'articles' table (Model: Article) where there is field named 'pageview'. Each Article has different number of pageview. I want to fetch those rows who holds top 10 pageviews. How can I fetch these data using eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the orderBy method which ordering data.
hence you need top 10 page views, you can do this.

```
orderBy('PageView','desc')
```

Now you have to take only 10 so use method take(). It actually means limit in MySQL. here's your code

```
Article::orderBy('PageView','desc')->take(10)->get();
```

Mysql query is now

```
select * from articles order by PageView desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first orderBy DESC the articles and then take out 10 records of the model. Try this!

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('pageview', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

It will do the trick:

```
Article::orderBy('PageView','Desc')->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Article::orderBy('PageView','DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

or (without column name)

```
Article::latest()->take(10)->get();
```